# How can I change the color of my statebins map?

Tags: r, colors, data-visualization

I'm trying to change the color of my statebins map. I'm super new to R and still learning a lot, and googling around hasn't really helped.

This is what the sample looks like:

```
   fipst stab                state color
1     37   NC       North Carolina     2
2      1   AL              Alabama     2
3     28   MS          Mississippi     2
4      5   AR             Arkansas     2
5     47   TN            Tennessee     2
6     45   SC       South Carolina     1
7     23   ME                Maine     2
49    32   NV               Nevada     1
50    15   HI               Hawaii     2
51    11   DC District of Columbia     2

 digitaltax <- structure(list(fipst = c(37L, 1L, 28L, 5L, 47L, 45L, 23L, 32L,15L, 11L), stab = c("NC", "AL", "MS", "AR", "TN", "SC", "ME","NV", "HI", "DC"), state = c("North Carolina", "Alabama", "Mississippi","Arkansas", "Tennessee", "South Carolina", "Maine", "Nevada","Hawaii", "District of Columbia"), color = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L,2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L)), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L,7L, 49L, 50L, 51L), class = "data.frame") 

    ==X==============================================================X==

        mutate(
      digitaltax, 
      share = cut(color, breaks = 3, labels = c("No sales tax", "Exempts digital goods", "Taxes digital goods"))
    ) %>% 
      statebins(
        value_col = "share", font_size = 2.5,
        ggplot2_scale_function = scale_fill_brewer,
        name = ""
      ) +
    labs(title = "Which states tax digital products?") + theme_statebins()
```

This produces a map with a range of blues. How can I change the color? No matter what I've tried and found on google, it always throws this error:

```
Error in ggplot2_scale_function(...) : could not find function "ggplot2_scale_function"
```

Any help at all would be super appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Hi Kathy, welcome to Stack Overflow. `ggplot2_scale_function` is not a function. Perhaps you were reading somewhere that suggested you used a scale function from ggplot2? If you can provide at least a sample of `digitaltax`, we can likely be of assistance. You can try `dput(digitaltax)`. You can edit your question and paste the output. You can surround it with three backticks (```) for better formatting. See [How to make a reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/) for more info.

Comment: For the colors, try using [one of the color palettes here](https://www.datanovia.com/en/blog/the-a-z-of-rcolorbrewer-palette/). I'm not familiar with `statebins()`, but in the documentation it looks like there's an option to specify colors like `brewer_pal = "PuBu" `

Comment: @Ian Campbell, I've added a sample - thank you for all of that important info. I hope that helps!

Comment: It took me forever to figure out that you're using the development version of `statebins`. In the future, if you're using a version that is not in CRAN, please mention that in the question.

Comment: Sorry @Ian-Campbell I saw the github version had the parameter she was using and went there first.

Comment: Kathy if that solved your problem please mark the answer correct

Answer (score 1):

With your data and most of your code I did change DC color to 3 so it shows all categories.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(statebins)

# changes DC to be color 3
digitaltax <- structure(list(fipst = c(37L, 1L, 28L, 5L, 47L, 45L, 23L, 32L,15L, 11L), stab = c("NC", "AL", "MS", "AR", "TN", "SC", "ME","NV", "HI", "DC"), state = c("North Carolina", "Alabama", "Mississippi","Arkansas", "Tennessee", "South Carolina", "Maine", "Nevada","Hawaii", "District of Columbia"), color = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L,2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L)), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L,7L, 49L, 50L, 51L), class = "data.frame")

mutate(
  digitaltax, 
  share = cut(color, breaks = 3, labels = c("No sales tax", "Exempts digital goods", "Taxes digital goods"))
) %>% 
  statebins(
    value_col = "share", font_size = 2.5,
    ggplot2_scale_function = scale_fill_brewer,
    name = ""
  ) +
  labs(title = "Which states tax digital products?") + 
  theme_statebins()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-05-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: thank you for taking the time to help. Yes, this is basically the map that I get with the range of blues. Were you able to change the color palette somehow? I have added my data as well.

Comment: It was `ggplot2_scale_function = ggplot2::scale_fill_distiller` that was the issue one sec and I'll use your data

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to use named `RColorBrewer` palates with `brewer_pal =`:

```
library(statebins)
statebins(digitaltax,
          value_col = "color",
          breaks = length(unique(digitaltax$share)),
          labels = unique(digitaltax$share),
          brewer_pal = "Dark2") +
  labs(title = "Which states tax digital products?")
```

[image]

Execute this command to see all palates:

```
library(RColorBrewer)
display.brewer.all()
```

[image]